# How to return a Boolean as an expressiont to replace if, else true and false

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to solve a challenge in freecodecamp and I dont want to write twice return true and false. 
Instead I am looking for minimizing code and write an expression that evaluates to a boolean

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {

    if(str.substr(-target.length) === target){

        //Code that evaluates and returns and expression as a boolean 

    }

}

console.log(confirmEnding("Connor" , "n"));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you give an example of some code that replaces the comment?

Comment: I havent resolved it yet. is this one: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/confirm-the-ending

Answer (score 0):

Simply return the boolean value of evaluating the expression

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  return str.substr(-target.length) === target;
}

console.log(confirmEnding("hello", "lo"));
console.log(confirmEnding("loollo", "lo"));
console.log(confirmEnding("leo", "lo"));
```

Here is another way

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  return str.lastIndexOf(target) + target.length === str.length;
}

console.log(confirmEnding("hello", "lo"));
console.log(confirmEnding("loollo", "lo"));
console.log(confirmEnding("leo", "lo"));
```